# "is" vs "has" for temperature

Tags: grammar

When describing the temperature of an object, is it more correct to say "the object is 20 degrees", or "the object has 20 degrees"?

Does this depend on context? If only one is correct, what does the other mean? When was this difference established?

Comment: *The water is 20 degrees*. We never use *has* here.

Comment: la agua tiene veinte grados pero The water is 20 degrees. The other doesn't mean anything as it stands but if you added 'of tilt', for example, it might start to have meaning.

Comment: Less deleted versions are 'The water is at a temperature of 20 degrees' and 'The water has a temperature of 20 degrees'. 'The water is 20 degrees' is an accepted form.

Comment: If you have 20 doctorates, you can have 20 degrees.  Otherwise, use is. :-)

Comment: Of course, your child is staying home from school because she *has* a temperature.

Answer (score 1):

It is incorrect to say, 'the object has 20 degrees'.

If you are writing formally (as in a scientific paper) I would say neither. My versions would be

*The temperature of the water is 20 degrees.*

*The water temperature is 20 degrees.*

*Keep the water at 20 degrees.*

Informally many people would say

*The water is 20 degrees.*

Comment: In a scientific paper, of course, you would also specify the temperature system -- Kelvin, Celsius, or even Fahrenheit. (But since 'water' is the object in this example, we know it has to be Celsius.)